# Django Multiple search in one html search field + selectpicker = how to change value of action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, search

I hope you're well.

I've different search views :

#search profile in user app ({% url 'user:userprofile_result' %})

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login/'),name="dispatch")
class UserProfileResultsView(ListView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'search_results_user.html' 
    
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

#search article in nutriscore app ({% url 'search_results' %})

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'search_results.html' 
    
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(slug__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

...

I'd like to have all this searchs in one form with Dropdown (something like that):
Anyone has an idea about it? Thanks in advance,

```
            <form action="???" method="get" class="div-only-desk mr-2 my-auto w-100 order-1">
             <div class="input-group">
<div class="dropdown">
  <select class="selectpicker bouton-catego dropdown-toggle">
  <optgroup label="Nutriscore">
    <option value="{% url 'search_results_autor' %}">Autor</option>
    <option value="{% url 'search_results' %}">Nutri</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cooker">
    <option value="{% url 'user:userprofile_result' %}">Find a cooker</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
<input class="form-control border border-right-0h" name="q" type="text" placeholder="{{ q }}" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `TemplateView` instead, the code would go like this:

```
class SearchResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search_results.html' 
    
    query1 = request.GET.get('q1')
    articles = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(slug__icontains=query)
    )

    profiles = request.GET.get('q2')
    object_list = UserProfile.objects.filter(
        Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query)
    )
    
    args = {'profiles': profiles, 'articles': articles}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

You can check for results using `{% if profiles %}`,  `{% if articles %}` and display them only if they are present, you also would have to do bit of styling to display the results as a list.

Comment: thanks foy your answer Arun :) but is there any way to use a variable in <form action="variable"...> in relation with the value of selectpicker?

Comment: Yeah, you can define a JavaScript function which changes the value of that variable when the select value is changed (using `onchange` event handler on select).